# Is it possible to have arbitrary key names in pydantic?

Tags: python, types, pydantic

I am trying to emulate a similar behavior to typescripts interface with arbitrary key names for a `pydantic` model, but am running in to some issues.

Consider the following in TS:

```
export interface SNSMessageAttributes {
    [name: string]: SNSMessageAttribute;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this in pydantic?

Here is my python example code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as
from typing import Optional

class Values(BaseModel):
    Value: str
    Type: str

class MessageAttributes(BaseModel):
    ArbitraryKey: Optional[Values]


class Mymodel(BaseModel):
    MessageAttributes: Optional[MessageAttributes]


data = {"MessageAttributes": {"ArbitraryKey": {"Type": "String", "Value": "TestString"}}}

parsed = parse_obj_as(Mymodel, data)

print(parsed.MessageAttributes.ArbitraryKey.Value)
# TestString
```

In this example, the property `ArbitraryKey` can be anything. But I cant possibly hardcode all the possible key names there could be. For instance, instead of `ArbitraryKey`, what if the key name was `SomeTestKey`?

I know I can use `extra = 'allow` in `Config`, but that wouldnt give the dot syntax that I can get when using `parse_obj_as`

My question is, if possible, can I do something similar to `[name: string]` in pydantic for property names?

Comment: I think it would be possible to do with [custom root type](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) but it does not [work as expected](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1193)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a discussion is [Github](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1802), this is doing exactly what I was hoping for.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as
from typing import Dict, Optional

from pydantic import parse

class Values(BaseModel):
    Value: str
    Type: str


class Mymodel(BaseModel):
    MessageAttributes: Optional[Dict[str, Values]]


data = {"MessageAttributes": {"ArbitraryKey": {"Type": "String", "Value": "TestString"}}}

parsed = Mymodel.parse_obj(data)

print(parsed)
print(parsed.MessageAttributes['ArbitraryKey'].Type)
```